# Loading HTML Pages with ability to go to previous one

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML pages, P1 and P2. I will first load the Page P1 into my iframe. Then i again will load the second HTML Page P2 into the same iframe, either using a link from P1 or outside iframe.

Now, when i close P2, using a javascript button action, then the Previous P1 should be shown, after closing P2. Pls advise me if this is possible and if yes, how.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
<button onclick="history.back()">Button text</button>
```

inside P2.

Comment: But will it retain the previous state of P1. I mean on loading P2 over P1, P1 should never be refreshed. On closing P2, P1 should be available in the state where the user left the same. I see gmail work in this way. Pls advise.

Comment: GMail doesn't load new HTML pages. It loads information from the server and updates the page via JavaScript. If you want it that way you must completely do the page with JavaScript.